# Akka.net PostgreSQL Peristence Slow startup time

Tags: postgresql, event-sourcing, akka.net, akka-persistence

We have a .NET 2.2 application and we are using Akka and Akka.Persistence with PostgreSQL for journal and snapshots. We have a large journal with approximately 2 million events and 42,000 unique persistence ids (all ids are GUIDs). We have always had a problem with startup times in our application. Sometimes it takes up to 20 minutes for the persistent actors to become responsive. The strange thing is that it still takes a long time even for persistent actors with snapshots or with no journal events.

After some digging into the PostgreSQL logs I found that on startup the following query runs every time:

```
2020-01-10 07:37:13 UTC-5e1825a8.b4c04-LOG:  duration: 966726.226 ms  execute <unnamed>: 
                    SELECT DISTINCT e.persistence_id as PersistenceId 
                    FROM public.event_journal e
```

You can see that this is taking a REALLY long time in our production/test environment, and I assume that this is the cause of the slow startup.

I would like to know:

1. Why does Akka.Persistence need to know all these ids if I'm already providing it with a specific persistence id for each actor?
2. Is there anything I can do to disable this behaviour? I would ideally like our startup times to be close to zero.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried adding index on that column (`public.event_journal.persistence_id`)?

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't seem to improve the performance at all - here are my results on local (https://pastebin.com/Je5E7TZr). Will also try it on our test environment later.

Comment: I had some success yesterday with including the Akka source code into my project and then changing two lines of SQL which reference AllPersistenceIdsSql to `AllPersistenceIdsSql = $@";";` to prevent the query from running. The startup was fast and the query did not run.

What is the risk of doing this? Can I override this behavior without writing my own custom journal implementation.

Comment: @BartoszSypytkowski I worked a bit on a fork of the Akka.Persistence.PostgreSQL and I overrode the `AroundPreStart()` method to not call `base.AroundPreStart()`. This seems to have solved the issue and it is no longer fetching all distinct persistence IDs on startup. I'm not sure if I might break anything by overriding this default behaviour of the SqlJournal however. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @BartoszSypytkowski Forked and made this PR - https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Akka.Persistence.PostgreSql/pull/68 - let me know if you think that solution makes sense